# My log4j2 log file always have double output of each line

Tags: java, logging, duplicates, log4j2

I have seen a lot of posts about duplicate entries on log using log4j2. The solution seems to be add the additivity attribute and set it to false, but it seems is not working for me.

Here's my log4j2.xml

```
 <Configuration status="DEBUG">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" additivity="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
    <File name="File" fileName="C:\Laguna\Logs\Laguna.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MM-yyy HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="off">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="br.com.flutuante.laguna" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I'm having duplicate logs in both console and file logs.
I have tried add additivity="false" everywhere and even removed ROOT entry but can't get it right.

Can anyone help me?

Maybe i'm coding the class wrong?

I'm doing this to get the logger object...

```
static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Laguna.class.getName());
```

and using it like this...

```
logger.info("Arquivo de configuração carregado");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because you are missing a Root logger, try adding one with level="OFF" if you don't want any other logs.

Edit: Not sure if this is what you want, it should turn off all logging except the specified loggers:

```
<Logger name="br.com.flutuante.laguna" level="trace"/>
<Root level="off">
    <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
</Root>
```

or just change the level in Root to set a default logging level while setting the specified logger to trace

Comment: I had the Root level, but tried to remove it to see if would work like i want... I put it on the example again. I had not tried the level='off' before, but even with it, i'm still getting duplicate logs. Thanks for the help

Comment: Just to clarify, if your Logger is using the same appenders as Root you don't need to specify them again, instead remove additivity="false" and leave it empty: `<Logger name="br.com.flutuante.laguna" level="trace"></Logger>`. Still, additivity="false" should have worked too...

Comment: Now I'm getting just the first line of the log duplicate... that's good enough for me for now. Thanks buddy.